# Matrix operations on objects in a list

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list like the one below containing matrices that I want to do separate operations on.

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(data = c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2), nrow = 8, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE) )
matrix_list <- list(data[1:4, ], data[5:8, ])
```

I know I can do matrix operations on each object separately, like this

```
eigen(matrix_list[[1]])
```

And I can do an operation on all items with a `for` loop

```
for (i in 1:2){print(eigen((data_list[[i]])))}
```

How can I skip the `for` loop and operate on the list directly?  It would be great if i could just do something like "eigen(matrix_list)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lapply` to operate over a list

```
lapply(matrix_list, eigen)
[[1]]
[[1]]$values
[1] 1 1 1 1

[[1]]$vectors
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0


[[2]]
[[2]]$values
[1] 2 2 2 2

[[2]]$vectors
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0
```

If you're interested only on values or vectors you can just select them using:

```
Eigen <- lapply(matrix_list, eigen)
> sapply(Eigen, '[', 'values') # Extrating eigen values
$values
[1] 1 1 1 1

$values
[1] 2 2 2 2

> sapply(Eigen, '[', 'vectors') # Extrating eigen vectors
$vectors
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0

$vectors
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0

>
```